# Django: Query works fine with Sqlite3, don't with others Database Management System

Tags: django, database, django-orm, database-management

I have quite long query with 'Q()', with `Sqlite3` works very well, but with `postgresql` or `mysql` I have strange error e.g. for postgresql: `invalid input syntax for integer: "("`
 and for mySQL: `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '('`

How could I run that query with mysql? Where is my mistake?

Here is that query:

```
    watchersTuple = self.getWatchers()
    tagsTuple = self.getTags()
    blockedUserTuple = self.getBlockedUser()
    blockedTagTuple = self.getBlockedTag()

    statuses = Status.objects.filter( (Q(author__in = str(watchersTuple)) | Q(tags__in = str(tagsTuple)) | Q(author = self) | Q(recipient = self)) & ~Q(author__in = str(blockedUserTuple)) & ~Q(tags__in = str(blockedTagTuple)) ).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your models, but it looks like `author` is an integer field, or maybe a foreign key. In which case, why are you using `str` on the tuple of values? You presumably want to check whether author is one of those values. So just remove the `str` call.

The reason it appears to work in sqlite is that sqlite ignores field types - strings and integers are treated the same. Other DBMSs are more strict.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing obvious looking at the query. It would be useful to compare the raw queries for the Sqlite3 and MySql. This [link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/) shows you how to switch the SQL query debugging on.